# babel-standalone not transpilling esm module

Tags: vue.js, requirejs, babeljs, vue-class-components

I want to write vue demo for education teaching purpose, in order to focus only the vue part, I don't want to introduce npm, bundler like webpack or browserify and so on.

So I write code using `babel-standalone`. I also want to use `vue-class-component`. But now I could not use the `esm` build of `vue` and `vue-class-component`, in short I want to support write code like this in my main.js

```js
import Vue from '../vender/vue.esm.browser';
import Component from '../vender/vue-class-component.esm';

@Component
class App extends Vue {
//......
}
```

If I wrote the code like above, I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` eror.

Now I can make it work using the following style, but using the `Component` of `vue-class-component` is ugly.

```html
  <!-- the html contain these scripts -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-class-component@7.1.0/dist/vue-class-component.js"></script>
  <script src="vender/babel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- fix regenerator not defined -->
  <script src="vender/regenerator-runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"
    data-plugins="transform-runtime,transform-class-properties,transform-decorators-legacy,transform-regenerator"
    data-presets="es2015,stage-1" type="text/babel">
  </script>
```

```js
// js/main.js
const Component = VueClassComponent.default;

@Component
class App extends Vue {
//......
}
```

more details can found on https://github.com/liudonghua123/todos/tree/master/todos-vue-class-component

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to data-plugins: "transform-es2015-modules-umd"